# Delphi object reference model

Tags: delphi, memory-management

I am trying to understand precisely how Delphi manages the memory and I have read from Marco Cantu that it uses references like Java does.

I have understood that a variable (let's say `var theObj: TSomeClass;`) holds a reference (= a pointer) to indicate the memory location where the object has been stored. So when I call the constructor of `theObj` I am creating the class on the heap and then theObj is a pointer to the newly created location.

---

So far so good but now I have the doubt. He says that:

> In some OOP languages, declaring a variable of a class type creates an
>   instance of that class.

Does this mean that a pointer to a memory location is **not** involved? My guess is that here you declare a variable and it directly creates the object without using the heap. So is the variable only create on the stack and it holds all the data of the class?

---

**Note**. The guess and the question above are made because I made a comparison with C++.

- Delphi: `theObj := TSomeClass.Create`
- C++: `TSomeClass *theObj = new TSomeClass;`

Not going off topic and talking of C++ (it was just as example, I know only this language to make the comparison) but here in both cases I create the object in the heap and I have a pointer to it. The second question I made above came out because of this: in C++ I can also create an object like this `TSomeClass theObj;` and it will live until the end of the scope of the function.

In Delphi I cannot. I think that marco refers so this when he says "declaring a variable of a class type creates an instance of that class". Am I correct?

Comment: I think you may be reading him wrong, when he says "In some OOP languages, declaring a variable ..." he is drawing a distinction between those languages and Delphi.  In the very next sentence, he says "Delphi, instead, is based on an object reference model..  Note the **instead**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marco is thinking of C++ where classes and structs are essentially the same with different default accessibility. In C++

```
SomeClass obj;
```

creates the object.

There is nothing for you to worry about. Your understanding, as expressed in the second paragraph, is impeccable. A Delphi variable of class type is, under the hood, just a pointer to the instance.

Comment: This took me 2 days, thanks for your confirm now I know that it's correct. I see that Delphi and C++ both use the pointer to memory thing but C++ also has another way to create an object and he was referring to it. Thank you a lot btw!